# Xcode Webview Internet Connection alert

Tags: ios, xcode

so i have finished making my application and i am wondering is it mandatory to add code that checks if the user has a valid connection to the internet or not? one of the reasons I'm asking this is because in my previous app i used this piece of code below.

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView*) webview didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Important" message:@"Sorry, 
 it seems you are not currently connected to a network, please try again later." delegate:self    
cancelButtonTitle:@"I understand" otherButtonTitles: nil];

 [alert show];
 }
```

I used this i believe with Xcode 4 and iOS 6 i believe has something changed in the Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7, or am i doing something wrong. Sorry to sound stupid but its really bugging me.

Thank you

Comment: there is not necessary to put such a this type of alert.there apple not announce this type of thing.

Comment: ohh thanks, i read somewhere that it was needed to pass review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not needed, and is not specified anywhere in Apple's terms and conditions. However, it is kind of a standard procedure to warn your user if he encounters some kind of problem. I would strongly suggest that you implement these delegate methods.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment but i have tried to implement this piece of code however it doesn't work? sorry to sound stupid